# Update Environment Variable when changes made from My Computer

Tags: visual-studio-2008, winapi, visual-c++, environment-variables

I have a C++ program that calls `GetEnvironmentVariable()` to get the 'Path' variable information. If I am running my program, and meanwhile, I change my 'Path' variable via "MyComputer->Properties->Environment Variables"?... is it 100% impossible to retrieve the **updated** 'Path' variable from `GetEnvironmentVariable()` without restarting my program (and Visual Studio).

In [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049909/vc-doesnt-detect-newly-created-env-variable-using-getenvironmentvariable?rq=1), [Anders K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45685/anders-k) mentions:

> "Make sure you restart the application before you can read the environment variable. The same happens if you have a console window open and change the environment variables on My Computer, these are not noted in any existing console windows. You need to restart them to get a copy of the new environment variables."

Does this mean that there is 100% no way to retrieve the **updated** "Path" variable? I am unsure if I am wasting my time or not.

Also, I attempted something like [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/104011), but was not successful.

Thank you.

Comment: Just a thought, rather than a solution... but you could try starting another (short-lived) process from within your program and use that to read the environment variable

Comment: You should look into CreateEnvironmentBlock (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  I haven't used it before, so posting as a comment instead of an answer, but it looks like that should work for you.

Comment: Or, to echo @andypaxo, shell execute "cmd: ECHO %PATH%", but be sure to not create the cmd process as a child of your existing process or it will just inherit your environment block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the advice of the helpful responders, I decided to use registry keys to get updated Environment Variables instead.

Assuming:

```
    DWORD BufferSize = 16383;  
    TCHAR pathVar[16383];
```

Before, I did:

```
    GetEnvironmentVariable(_T("Path"),pathVar,16383);
```

Which never gave me the updated Path environment variable, if I updated via My Computer->Properties.

Now, I do:

```
    DWORD dwRet = RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
    _T("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\Environment"), 
    _T("Path"), RRF_RT_ANY, NULL, (PVOID)&pathVar, &BufferSize);

    if(dwRet != ERROR_SUCCESS){
        GetEnvironmentVariable(_T("Path"),pathVar,16383);
    }
```

Which gets the value from the registry key. But, if for some reason `RegGetValue()` fails, it will get the value via `GetEnvironmentVariable()`, which may not be fully updated, but atleast I get a value that I may be able to use. Thank you everyone for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Well, not 100% impossible.  Editing the environment variables like that only sets registry keys.  You can see them back with Regedit.exe, navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment, you'll see the list of values you saw back in the editing box.  The user specific ones are stored in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment.

The key then is exactly *when* a process starts using these values.  Which depends, a process can inherit the environment from the process that started it, the lpEnvironment argument for CreateProcess() determines this.  Passing a NULL and thus inheriting is very common, so the started process won't see the changes, it got a copy of the stale environment from its parent.  The only way to be really sure is to log-off and log back on so you know for a fact that such a process got started with the changed environment.  Or just try it so you know.

The not 100% impossible angle is to actually read these registry keys.  Not exactly very practical and of course entirely un-portable.  The PATH environment variable is really only useful when launching programs from a shell.

Answer (score 2):

If you need it to be dynamic in that sense then you are using the wrong thing.  Don't use environment variables, use something like registry entries.

Answer (score 1):

The environment variables don't come directly from the registry to your app, they are read once by Explorer then passed/inherited by any child processes it creates. There is however a mechanism that allows an application, when it changes the registry values, to tell applications to reload these values using the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` broadcast message with `lParam` pointing to a string containing "Environment".

Normally, only Explorer honours this message, but you can detect it in your own application and re read the data directly from the registry.